# User Cannot See Lookup Field Even if the Field is Visible on the Page Layout

Tags: lookup, page-layout, administration, developer

User cannot see a lookup field, even though its shows on page layout.

i checked the permissions of object they have all permissions, check assigned page layouts and field visibility as well. what can be the issue in this?

Comment: do they have (view) access to the object the lookup field is looking up to?

Comment: Yes they do.!!!

Comment: can you, as an admin, see the field on the layout?

Comment: Yes, i can see the field.

Comment: Only other reasons I could think of are that this is possibly a Dynamic Lightning Record Page or it is a caching issue (only if you made a recent change to the layout and/or settings).

Comment: Can you try steps mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000326130&type=1)

Comment: Hi Vinay, i did but still the result is same.